# Change icons in Big Picture Mode

Tags: steam

I've got some non-Steam games that support controllers, but Big Picture Mode only shows them as big generic Steam logos, making them very hard ti pick out from the pack (big picture only shows names on "hover"). In "small picture" mode these games use the Windows icons, which is fine.

How can I set an icon, however ugly, to these games? What format/dimensions should it optimally be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opt into the client beta and icons for non-Steam games will show up in Big Picture.  If the program's icon has high resolution versions it will use them automatically.  PNG is also supported and will get scaled to fit.

Currently the icons for non-Steam games will not be visible to streaming clients.

Comment: I'm in the client beta, I still see the steam Icon and mesh logo on all my non-steam stuff. There's only one Beta, right? Does it have to be a separate icon in the folder, not the icon the .exe is using? Icons show up fine outside of big picture

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka:  Try checking for client updates, or restarting so it happens automatically.  It will be in a very recent client update.  If that doesn't help, try changing the icon (even back to the same thing) from the desktop UI (right click properties on the shortcut).  Let me know if it works.

Comment: build is from april 2nd, checked for updates. What date do you show? I'm in the home streaming beta in case that's messing with it somehow

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka: You're right, it's not working in Apr 2, was working on my (out of date) late Mar build.  It will probably be back in the next update, but that won't be for at least a week and a half.

Comment: At some point the Beta seems to have corrected itself, I get the icons now